# IErrorInfo.GetDescription - SELECT query not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am using the following SQL statement for MS Access:

```
Public Function GetSectionID(ByVal Course As String, ByVal YrLvl As Integer, ByVal Section As String) As Integer
    If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Connection.Open()
    End If

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT SectionID FROM tblCourses WHERE Course = '" & Course & "' AND (YrLevel = " & YrLvl & " AND Section = '" & Section & "')"
    Dim comd As New OleDbCommand(sql, Connection)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = comd.ExecuteReader

    Dim int As Integer = -1

    If reader.HasRows Then
        While reader.Read
            int = CInt(reader.Item(0))
            Exit While
        End While
    End If
    Return int
End Function
```

When I execute the program, it returns with an error:

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: `Section` is a reserved word.  Try adding brackets `[Section]` .Check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=70d229f8-26f4-47d1-904d-27da662abd4c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010030643

Comment: also, that x8000 hints and suggests that you not forced the project to x86. Under build ->configuration manager - under the Active solution platform drop down choose new and for the new platform choose x86.